# iterate in json array like foreach in C#

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json object array[image: contents view in chrome dev. console], and need to iterate this array in objects only

somethink like that:

```
if(Passed)
foreach(var item in object)
alert(item.NAME+""+item.IP);
```

of course I need achieve this in jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/y3n3rrr/so84wLuc/

Comment: can you create fiddle with object??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar unfortunately don't know use fiddle but I should. too many solution includes that.. but this time let it be without it :)

Comment: it will be easy to debug and get the solution if you share the fiddle. you only need to set the json object as variable.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I think this is it you ask for. it looks in dev console like this. I hope it helps to figure.

Comment: would be great if you can set the var data to actual json variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will get your `object` through `data1` from the figure.

You can use jquery `each` function to iterate through your object.

It would go as below:

```
   if(data1.Passed)
    {
           $.each(data1,function(index,value){
                alert(value.Name + " " + value.IP);
           });
    }
```